# How to split a string by separator?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a String `a="-4--5-6"`
When i execute `a.split("-")` Result is {4,5,6} but i want `{4,-5,6}`. what regular expression to ask to get an answer?

Comment: How would you know it's not `{-4, 5, -6}`?

Comment: `a.split("(?<=\\d)-");`

Comment: I meant -4, -5, 6 actually, since the OP appears to be splitting on `-` *between* positive or negative numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positive look-behind to look for a `-` that follows a number:

```
a.split("(?<=\\d)-");
```

The `(?<=u)` is the positive look-behind, where `u` represents the chars that are being looked behind for, and the `\\d` represents any numeric char. This will look for `-` that follows a number, but does not include that number in the captured chars so the split does not delete the number, just the `-` char.

e.g.,

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String a = "-4--5-6";
        System.out.println(a);

        String[] b = a.split("(?<=\\d)-");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    }
}
```

Note that this will return

```
[-4, -5, 6]
```

Since the first 4 is preceded by a negative sign

For more on this, please check out [this regular expressions tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

For your example where String is:

```
String a = "1-2--3-4";
```

This will return:

```
[1, 2, -3, 4]
```

Which is exactly what you want

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    String a = "1-2--3-4";
    System.out.println(a);

    String[] b = a.split("(?<=\\d)-");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
}
```

Comment: example: a=(1-2--3-4). i want to get (1,2,-3,4). your regex don't work for this example

Comment: @Alex please see edit to answer, since this code does in fact work in that situation